# Why doesn't input :: - webkit-slider-thumb, input :: - moz-slider-thumb work?

Tags: css

creating a small slider for ego support not only in webkit browsers has to use a scss template like

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  height: 1vmin;
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 2vmin;
  height: 2vmin;
  background: red;
}

input::-moz-range-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  -moz-appearance: none;
       appearance: none;
  width: 2vmin;
  height: 2vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <input type="range">
</body>

</html>
```

where -webkit-slider-thumb and -moz-range-thumb are on different lines, but why a variant like

```css
input {
  width: 100%;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  height: 1vmin;
}

input::-webkit-slider-thumb, input::-moz-range-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 2vmin;
  height: 2vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<body>
    <input type="range">
</body>

</html>
```

does not work? I noticed this feature only with the properties of the engines

Answer (score 4):

It works in Firefox (at least on my Windows10 laptop).

On Chrome/Edge it does not work, as noted in the question.

In fact, any prefix other than -webkit seems to render the entire set of selectors invalid or at least ignored.

For example in:

```
input::-webkit-slider-thumb, input::-webkit-range-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 2vmin;
  height: 2vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

the slider thumb is styled correctly, but in this:

```
input::-webkit-slider-thumb, input::-rubbish-range-thumb {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;
  width: 2vmin;
  height: 2vmin;
  background: red;
}
```

the styling is ignored.

UPDATE:

I found this note on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Webkit_Extensions):

> Note: Generally, if there is an invalid pseudo-element or pseudo-class
> within in a chain or group of selectors, the whole selector list is
> invalid. If a pseudo-element (but not pseudo-class) has a -webkit-
> prefix, As of Firefox 63, Blink, WebKit and Gecko browsers assume it
> is valid, not invalidating the selector list.